# RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Qt5.6 
Во время дебага выскакивает данное сообщение. Что можно предпринять чтобы выявить причину и устранить её. В интернете информация по этому вопросу весьма расплывчата.

```
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QObject'
```

Ошибку выдаёт в функции после того как её выполнить и начинает пробегать повторно по строкам. После такого прохода на строке объявления переменной "EmailEdit e;" и выскакивает данная ошибка. Мне пока не совсем ясно что конкретно происходит во время окончательной пробежки и как это правильно называется.

```
QString ProviderSMTP::switchProvider(QString provider, QString pass)
{
  EmailEdit e;
  if (e.emailTrue(provider))
    {
      toConfigFile(setProvider(provider, pass));
    }
  else
    {
      toConfigFile(setProvider(showAllFreeProvider()));
    }

  return "";
}
```

В pro файле добавлено:

```
CONFIG   += rtti
```

Прототип функции EmailEdit:

```
class EmailEdit : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit EmailEdit(QObject *parent = 0);

  bool emailTrue (QString);
  QStringList emailExtract(QString); // проверить выдачу

signals:

public slots:

private:
  int right(QChar);
  int left(QChar);
  bool domain(QString);
};
```

Comment: Похоже, Вы используете с++ функции, которые используют rtti (например, dynamic_cast).

Comment: может ли это быть от зависания gui?

Comment: зависания gui обычно бывает от слишком длинных операций  (например, http запросы) в главном потоке).

А зачем Вам `CONFIG   += rtti` ? может удалить?

Comment: @KoVadim написал ответ. Можете ли вы описать что именно было не так и почему? Буду благодарен и зачту ваш ответ.

Comment: Я не телепат и угадать что там было - сложно. Но есть подозрение, что пробелема где то внутри класса EmailEdit.

Comment: @KoVadim добавил прототип функции в вопрос.

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы прекрасно понимаете, что прототип функции на то и прототип, что бы показать "лицо", а что там внутри - скрыть.  Но для решения задачи нужно смотреть внутрь.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43627/discussion-between-shaman888-and-kovadim).

Comment: Если у Вас новый вопрос - создайте новый вопрос, в чаты не хожу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась тем, что я заменил определение объекта на:

```
  EmailEdit *e = new EmailEdit;
```

Настройку:

```
CONFIG   += rtti
```

Удалил, но работает как с ней так и без неё. Она была установлена в процессе отладки в надежде что поможет.

Comment: ` EmailEdit *e = new EmailEdit;` - это не определение объекта. Это его создание в куче.

Comment: По-моему это называется "Cargo cult"